# Postfix - How to send bounces only to postmaster?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, email-bounces

I have an internal Postfix server where bounces are intentionally discarded (not recommended in general but needed for my use case).
I would like to enable it temporarily but only to the postmaster, not the sender.

Is that possible?

Currently when enabling bounces in master.cf it sends the bounce/NDR to both.

From the mail.log:

```
D93A53EDC2: sender non-delivery notification: DF0083EDCB
D93A53EDC2: postmaster non-delivery notification: E01303EDCC
```

From master.cf:

```
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
```

Comment: *internal* server generating bounces that are discarded? what is going on, are you sure whatever problem you are tackling is not better solved by not accepting undeliverable messages in the first place? what settings you you currently use to discard or enable?

Answer (score 1):

you have to set `notify_classes =`  in `main.cf`. And set `bounce_notice_recipient = postmaster` .